# Apache and nginx on different ports

Tags: apache, nginx, portforwarding

I'm trying to host two (personal) websites, one on nginx and another one on apache. I don't have any DNS setup for this.

So I've bound nginx to port 80 and apache to 9005. My internet router exposes port 9003 and forwards it to port 80 to the server hosting the sites. And it similarly maps 9005 to 9005 to the server.

The strange thing is, when I navigate my browser to my home IP on port 9003 the nginx site opens. But it also opens the nginx site (on port 9003) when navigating to my home IP on port 9005. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

edit: so the issue it seems is; Apache is forwarding the request towards port 9005 by default to 9003?

Comment: What happens when you navigate to the internal IP on port 9005?

Comment: strangely enough it also automatically redirects to port 9003

Comment: 9003 on your home IP or on the internal IP? Does anything answer if it's the internal IP? You should test with curl to rule out caching issues from your browser.

Comment: when using curl on the internal IP to port 9005, I get a 301 with the location header pointing to port 9003 also on the internal IP. would one of the two webservers do that?

Comment: oh I can see the server that's responding to port 9005 being nginx;

Comment: After updating nginx to not listen on port 9005, I can see the same 301 to 9003 but then (correctly) from Apache. Why is Apache forwarding the request?